# i want to put if else statement in store procedure but not find any solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

i want to put these conditions in my stored procedure

```
if ((select PriSubmissionStatusId from Claim where ClaimId = 375 )!= 106  ) Print 'Primary'
else if((select SecSubmissionStatusId from Claim where ClaimId = 375 )= 0)print 'Primary'
else if((select SecSubmissionStatusId from Claim where ClaimId = 375 )!= 106)print 'Secoundary'
else if((select OthSubmissionStatusId from Claim where ClaimId = 375 )= 0)print 'Secoundry'
else if((select OthSubmissionStatusId from Claim where ClaimId = 375 )!= 106)print 'Other'
else print 'Primary'
```

as column name build up, their is also other column in stored procedure which come from different table. any idea?

Comment: The conditions are confusing! LIke if SecSubmissionStatusId = 0, then SecSubmissionStatusId = 0 and SecSubmissionStatusId <> 106 are true! Can you please describe in detail with some sample data what you are really need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Case When` instead of `if else`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PriSubmissionStatusId <> 106   THEN 'Primary'
            WHEN SecSubmissionStatusId = 0      THEN 'Primary'
            WHEN SecSubmissionStatusId <> 106   THEN 'Secoundary'
            WHEN OthSubmissionStatusId = 0      THEN 'Secoundry'
            WHEN OthSubmissionStatusId <> 106   THEN 'Other'
        END
FROM  Claim 
WHERE ClaimId = 375
```

Comment: their also other columns in it, how can i use it.

Comment: please put your table data sample